# How to inflate view in other layout?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, layout-inflater

[image]

I have to create a horizental scrollview that contains boxes. Each box could at most contains only three items. So my logic is:

1. Create list of box in Horizental ScrollView

   ```
   <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/ll_list"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
   ```
2. Create box.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/ll_box"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

       </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Create item.xml for the item (in box)

In Java
For example, there are 7 item so I need 3 boxes. 
Here is my code,

```
public void initList(){
   View box = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.box, null);
   LinearLayout ll_box = (LinearLayout)box.findViewById(R.id.ll_box);
   int item = 7;
   int idx = item/3; //idx is a number of boxes
   if (item%3!=0)
       idx++;

    for (int i=0; i<idx; i++ ){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            ll_box.addView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item, null));
        }
        ll_list.addView(ll_box);
    }
}
```

And the problem is that I got error at
ll_list.addView(ll_box);
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

If you don't understand the problem please ask me. I really need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new `box` `View` on each step.

Something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<idx; i++ ){

   View box = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.box, null);
   LinearLayout ll_box = (LinearLayout)box.findViewById(R.id.ll_box);

   for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
       ll_box.addView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item, null));
   }
   ll_list.addView(box); //here add `box` instead of `ll_box`!!
}
```